# Running Robotium on a server

Tags: android, robotium

I'm trying to test my Android app on a Linux server with Robotium.

```
lt.socialheat.android.tests.SocialHeatTest:
Failure in testEventToMap:
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: View with id: '2131034182' is not found!
    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.getView(Solo.java:1929)
    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.getView(Solo.java:1909)
    at lt.socialheat.android.tests.SocialHeatTest.testEventToMap(SocialHeatTest.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
    at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)
```

Simple view not found exception, but the tests run fine on a local emulator, or an actual device. The server, being a server, doesn't have a monitor or any kind of GUI and I did get an error while creating the AVD about using software rendering instead of GLES. So is it possible to run Robotium tests on a server without GUI and how does one accomplish this feat?

EDIT:

emulator params:
android-17, intel ABI
emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a fully working Robotium environment on an EC2 instance before, so I can assure you that this feat is indeed possible.

You'll need to do the following things:

- **Run a VNC session** (`vnc4server, fluxbox`) and run the emulator instance from there. This would at least get rid of the zero display dilemma you've mentioned.
- Add the `-noaudio` flag when starting the emulator. It's a strange bug, but the emulator simply freezes as it starts up on a headless instance.
- Once the emulator has finished loading (check via adb status), remember that it starts with the lockscreen displayed. Unlock it by performing `adb shell input keyevent 82`

I've documented my own adventure in getting it done here, so feel free to check it out.
[Robotium EC2 Guide](http://jerieljan.blogspot.com/2013/01/robotium-jenkins-setup-guide-for-ec2.html)

Comment: I'll try that, but I'm working on a university server to which I don't have root access.

Comment: `adb shell input keyevent 82`
I think this fixed it, test completes successfully.